# Searching for "/" using awk

Tags: awk

I want to search for the `/` under `Mounted on` in the following df output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      471081708 82857660 364294432  19% /
udev             2046164        4   2046160   1% /dev
tmpfs             822540     1376    821164   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2056344      388   2055956   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1      228917696 21117560 195590336  10% /media/xtra
```

However, this command

`df | awk -F" " /\// '{print $6 "\t" $4}'`

results in this error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: ///
awk: cmd. line:1:    ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

How can I search for the `/` under `Mounted on`?

Comment: Since every line except te first contains a "/", what exactly is it you're trying to accomplish by searching for "/"? If it's just to skip the first line there's a much more obvious solution of `NR>1`

Comment: I'm trying to get the last "/", and you bring up a good point. I'll probably wind up getting line 2.

Comment: You'll get all lines with the posted solutions. What do you mean `the last "/"`? The last line or the last occurrence of "/" on each line? Please post the expected output from your sample input so we aren't guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern was outside the quotes:

```
$ df | awk '/\//{print $6 "\t" $4}'
```

You can also specify the output field separator at the beginning of the script:

```
$ df | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}/\//{print $6, $4}'

$ df | awk -v OFS="\t" '/\//{print $6, $4}'
```

But as [EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) points out everyline has at least one `/` beside the heading so you could drop the match and just skip the first line like:

```
$ df | awk 'NR>1{print $6 "\t" $4}'
```

Comment: Or, IOW, the pattern needs to be part of the same argument as the match.

Comment: Ugh to the change using BEGIN...it was better with the literal tab in the print string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler any reason beside style, It's what the `OFS` is for after all.

Comment: perhaps -v OFS='\t' is more palatable? Either way.... Since there's a "/" on every line but the header I really don't get what the OP is trying to do by searching for "/" anyway.

Comment: I'd argue clarity (and secondarily brevity) makes the first better.

Answer (score 1):

your pattern doesn't really make sense, because each line of your df output always contains a `/`. (except for the title)

if you want to reformat the output to `$6\t$4`:

```
df|awk '{print $6"\t"$4}'
```

if your pattern is just for skipping the title,you could:

```
 df|awk 'NR>1{print $6"\t"$4}'
```

if you just want to search exactly `/` (root partition):

```
df|awk '$6~/^\/$/{print $6"\t"$4}'
```